# merge [punishment-severity] into [disciplinary-actions]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [punishment-severity](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punishment-severity) tag has 5 questions and the following wiki excerpt (no wiki):

> Questions about weighting the severity of a punitive action against a user.

The [disciplinary-actions](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disciplinary-actions) tag has 3 questions and no wiki.

Some of the questions tagged [punishment-severity](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punishment-severity) look like they would be more properly tagged [disciplinary-actions](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disciplinary-actions), as they aren't specifically about choosing the *severity* of a punishment.

I think the former is a subset of the latter and doesn't need to separately exist.  The concept of "severity", as distinct from disciplinary action in general, is too narrow.

I propose that we merge these into [disciplinary-action](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disciplinary-action).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After thinking about this for a while, I have just issued the merge.

The only question in what used to be [punishment-severity](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punishment-severity) that was actually exclusively about the *severity* of punitive actions was [#80: Should punishment be recursive?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/80/should-punishment-be-recursive), while the others were primarily about issuing disciplinary action at all, or about snowballed effects of a certain chosen severity. These all fit well under [disciplinary-actions](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disciplinary-actions).

Personally, I still think the idea of [punishment-severity](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punishment-severity) has some merit, as there are likely people who have specific experience with that over other aspects of moderation. The questions we've seen for this up until now do not warrant such a tag, however.